# How can I disable the vertical scrolling of a NSScrollView ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I disable the vertical scrolling of a NSScrollView ?

I can't find a quick solution on Google.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicated:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626288/disable-scrolling-in-nstableview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could observe the content offset in [scrollViewDidScroll:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) and set the x value to the value you like.

Edit:
Ok, then. Have you seen this: [Constraining Scrolling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW7)?

Comment: I'm on mac, the link you gave me is for iOS

Comment: I've checked the link you passed me. I don't understand why I get null bounds: [scrolledView bounds] is (null).

Comment: Ya, the scrolledView is a NSClipView (just checked in the console) which is a subclass of NSView, so it should have bounds

Comment: The link above to "Constraining Scrolling" contains the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try this in NSScrollView subclass:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super scrollWheel:theEvent];

    if ([theEvent deltaY] != 0.0)
    {
        [[self nextResponder] scrollWheel:theEvent];
    }
}
```

Also you can log it by:

```
NSLog(@"user scrolled %f horizontally and %f vertically", [theEvent deltaX], [theEvent deltaY]);
```

Comment: This does not block automatic scrolling when reseting the bounds for example.

Answer (score 2):

I like Ivan's answer above. However, in my particular case, I had a table view (vertical scrolling) where each row contained a collection view (horizontal scrolling).

When users tried to scroll up/down, if there mouse was hovered over one of the collection views, they wouldn't be able to scroll up or down.

To resolve this, I subclassed the NSScrollView that contained the NSCollectionViews and I overrided this method with the following code:

```
override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)
{
    if (fabs(Double(event.deltaY)) > fabs(Double(event.deltaX))) {
        self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event);
    } else {
        super.scrollWheel(with: event);
    }
}
```

This way, it checks if the user is predominantly scrolling in one direction and handles it appropriately.

Answer (score -9):

was wondering if you came across

```
- (void)setHasVerticalScroller:(BOOL)flag;
```

to disable the vertical scrollbar ?

You can also set this in Interface Builder.

Comment: It hides the scroller, but the scrolling is still possible by gestures