# How can I disable horizontal scrolling for an NSScrollView?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsscrollview

I first tried disabled the scroll bar by setting:

```
scrollView!.hasHorizontalScroller = false
```

and that successfully worked, but I could still scroll from left to right by using my trackpad.
Is there a way to ensure that horizontal scrolling is completely disabled for an NSScrollView object?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
var scrollView = UIScrollView(frame:myFrame)
let scroll = CGSizeMake(myHeight, myFrame.size.width)
scrollView.contentSize = scroll
```

Fixes the frame width to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Comment: A similar approach worked. However, setting the contentSize of the NSScrollView was not permitted (it was a read only variable), but the general concept of your solution was valid. Thanks!

Comment: UIScrollView ≠ NSScrollView

Comment: Question is asking about NSScrollView.

Answer (score 7):

Even with a correct content size, I was still able to use two-finger gestures to scroll horizontally a bit before it snaps back into place.  To fix this, you can set the elasticity:

```
scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = .None
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mikepj's answer I also needed to do the following.
Modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38967734/4698501) to become:

```swift
override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.scrollWheel(with: event)
    
    if event.deltaX != 0 {
        super.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
    }
}
```

This may be because I was using an NSRulerView.